# How to convert mobile screen coordinates into LatLng without using Google Map in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, google-maps

The requirement is to render the simple image on the screen and based on the LatLng list get from the server need to bind it with the rendered image and draw a polygon over the image.

Comment: Have you tried Google Maps Static API (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/start)? This will return an image with your polygon on drawn on it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I haven't write code for that. I need some ideas to develop custom map. I think it's not map I just need to show network image and server gives us latitude and longitude list and need to draw polygon based on LatLng list and zoom in/out image and scroll image which works same as image.